# Need help understanding and explaining a problem in probability

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition

I have to understand and explain a kinda complicated math problem for a math fair coming up next week. It goes more or less like this (translated from Spanish):

> "$100$ people were asked about their preferences when playing sports. Of these, $50$ people played soccer, $40$ people played basketball, and $30$ people rode bikes. Also, $25$ people played both soccer and basketball, $15$ played soccer and rode bikes, and $12$ played basketball and rode bikes. Finally, only $5$ people played all three sports. The rest either didn't know or didn't answer."

a) Represent the proper Venn diagram for this problem.

b) Calculate the following probabilities: $P(\text{play soccer}), P(\text{play soccer and basketball}), P(\text{only ride bikes}), P(\text{do all three sports}), P(\text{does any of the sports}), P(\text{does none of these sports}).$

What I need to figure out is how I would go about finding the answer to this problem and also explaining it mathematically and visually to a bunch of bystanders. Does anybody have some tips or some guidelines to get my on my way?

Comment: I suggest you start by ommiting the first three paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this draw three cicrcles intersecting each other. Then start by filling the intersection of all three circle with 5.

25 played soccer and basketball. 5 out of them comes under intersection of all three. So now 20 left with soccer and basketball only.

10 for soccer and rode bikes only.

7 for basketball and rode bikes only.

We filled all intersections now.

People playing only basketball = 40 - Intersections in which basketball comes.

= 40 - ( 5 + 20 + 7 ) = 8

Similarly for only soccer and only rode bikes. You have Venn diagram.